# for loop iterations issues in R

Tags: for-loop

I am trying to get more familiar with function writing and ran into a problem that I've been trying to solve for 3 hours now. Here's the code:

```
test <- function (x) {
    for (i in x)
            print(x[i])
}
```

When I assign a few variables:

```
a <- c(0,1)
b <- c(1,2)
```

b works fine, but 'a' gets all screwed up:

```
> test(b)
[1] 1
[1] 2

> test(a)
numeric(0)
[1] 0
```

I figured that something is wrong with the way R is handling the ones and zeros in 'a'. but when I iterate the function at the command line, there are no issues.

```
print(a[1])
[1] 0
> print(a[2])
[1] 1
```

How is R treating the command differently in the function and outside of it? And why is 1 and 2 okay as 'x', but not 0 and 1?

Comment: The syntax for your for loop will iterate on the _values_ of `x` not on the _indices_ of `x`.

Comment: I just saw that! Thank you! I will look into how to tell the loop to look at the index, not the value.

Comment: I tried for (i in 1:length(x))  and it worked perfectly. I feel stupid. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for your for loop will iterate on the *values* of `x` not on the *indices* of `x`.  When you call `test(c(0,1))`, in the first iteration through the `for` loop `i` will have a value of 0.  This means you will be trying to `print` the 0-th element of the argument.  For numeric vectors, in R, this will always give `numeric(0)`, the R term for a numeric variable of length 0.  Someone with a better, more systematic knowledge of R will have to explain why this is a good thing, but in any case it isn't what I think you are after.

```
a <- c(0,1)
b <- c(1,2)

> a[0]
numeric(0)

> b[0]
numeric(0)
```

I think you want your function be something like

```
test2 <- function (x) {
     for (i in 1:length(x))
             print(x[i])
 }
```

Now we can compare your function `test` vs. `test2` with perhaps more informative inputs.

```
> test(c(101,202))
[1] NA
[1] NA
> test2(c(101,202))
[1] 101
[1] 202
```

Or did I miss what you were after in your original question?

Answer (score 2):

In your function ,

```
test <- function (x) {
    for (i in x)
            print(x[i]) ## you are print from the indexed value
}
```

thus in `test(a)`

your are printing :

```
print(a[1]) # gives the first item in the vector a
print(a[2]) # gives the second item in the vector a
```

in `test(b)`

```
print(b[0]) # gives Null, since R is 1-based
print(b[1]) # gives the first item in the vector b
```

and hence you get the outcome

If you want to print thru all the item in a vector, you can change your function to

```
test <- function (x) {
    for (i in 1:length(x))
            print(x[i]) ## you are print from the indexed value
}
```

Cheers,
Biobirdman